# How do you show that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!(n+2)}=1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been trying to understand the result of this sum:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!(n+2)}=\frac12+\frac13+\frac18+\frac1{30}+\frac1{144}+\dots=1$$
Could you show me how to obtain 1 as result?

Comment: It's a telescoping series. Try computing and simplifying the partial sums into a fraction; you might be able to spot the pattern.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that we can write

$$\frac{1}{n!(n+2)}=\frac{(n+2)-1}{(n+2)!}=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}-\frac{1}{(n+2)!}$$

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**
Let $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}=\exp(x)$.
Note that
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!(n+2)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^1x^{n+1}\, dx=\int_{0}^1\sum _{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}\, dx=\int_{0}^1x\exp(x)\, dx.
$$
Assumes knowledge of calculus.

Comment: Can you explain how you obtained the integral form?

Comment: @Szeto notice that $\int_0^1 x^{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+2} x^{n+2} \rvert_0^1 = \frac{1}{n+2}$